# Maven run unit test with @Ignore

Tags: java, maven, junit

Is it possible to run a junit test annotated with @Ignore from command line (maven)? Or do I have to remove the @Ignore annotation?

Comment: I guess you have to remove the annotation and better to use -DskipTests=true if you want to skip tests. Another option is to use different naming and use excludes for e.g. integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to remove the annotation and better to use -DskipTests=true if you want to skip tests. Another option is to use different naming and use excludes for e.g. integration tests.